# Is there a way to get element by XPath using JavaScript in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, xpath, document.evaluate

I am looking for something like:

```
getElementByXpath(//html[1]/body[1]/div[1]).innerHTML
```

I need to get the innerHTML of elements using JS (to use that in Selenium WebDriver/Java, since WebDriver can't find it itself), but how?

I could use ID attribute, but not all elements have ID attribute.

Comment: Incidentally, the `html` and `body` selectors are superfluous since a DIV must be a descendent of BODY (immediate or deeper) and BODY must be a child of HTML, so provided there are no other DIV elements in the document, `//DIV[1]` should work (though I'm pretty rusty on XPath expressions). The DOM equivalent is `document.getElementsByTagName('div')[1]` (or maybe `0`).

Answer (score 723, accepted):

You can use `document.evaluate`:

> Evaluates an XPath expression string and returns a result of the
>   specified type if possible.

It is [w3-standardized](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#XPathEvaluator-evaluate) and whole documented: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.evaluate

```js
function getElementByXpath(path) {
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}

console.log( getElementByXpath("//html[1]/body[1]/div[1]") );
```

```html
<div>foo</div>
```

https://gist.github.com/yckart/6351935

There's also a great introduction on mozilla developer network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#document.evaluate

---

Alternative version, using `XPathEvaluator`:

```js
function getElementByXPath(xpath) {
  return new XPathEvaluator()
    .createExpression(xpath)
    .evaluate(document, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE)
    .singleNodeValue
}

console.log( getElementByXPath("//html[1]/body[1]/div[1]") );
```

```html
<div>foo/bar</div>
```

Comment: What does the magic number 9 mean? It would be better to use a named constant here.

Comment: @WillSheppard `XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE === 9` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#First_Node

Comment: I wrote an getElementByXPath function that has support for IE but some basic xpath support for now. There is also a function getElementXpath in there and they work nicely together for what I needed.
https://gist.github.com/Joopmicroop/10471650

Comment: @CiroSantilli Yes sir, it is: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#XPathEvaluator-evaluate

Comment: var xpathResult = document.evaluate( xpathExpression, contextNode, namespaceResolver, resultType, result );

Comment: How could this method be adapted in the context of a driver object? (I'm using WD.js for tests over Appium)

Comment: @AlexanderFradiani Have you tried `driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath())`?

Comment: How about xpath like this will not work. `"//*[text()[normalize-space() = 'HomePage' ]]"`

Comment: How would we use this method to set the calendar value in Angular JS application

Comment: This answer helped me greatly. In the end, I wanted to scroll a parent container of a ul, and here is a working scroll-down action, thanks to `evaluate` from this answer: `document.evaluate('//ul[@class="nav"]/..', document, null, 9).singleNodeValue.scrollTo(0, 1000)`

Comment: This seems to reload the page.

Answer (score 313):

In Chrome Dev Tools you can run the following:

```
$x("some xpath")
```

Comment: I've played around with this and it seems to work, but is there any documentation for this feature?  I didn't find anything.

Comment: This needs to be higher up. Firefox supports it, too.

Comment: @Eric Documentation: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities#xpath

Comment: Indeed. But Selenium does not find everything that works with `$x("")`.

Comment: $x wont work within script, it for console only. The accepted answer works within scripts running in browser context.

Comment: @Ben use Puppeteer : https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer

Answer (score 37):

To identify a [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) and [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) you have to use the [`evaluate()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#XPathEvaluator-evaluate) method which evaluates an *xpath* expression and returns a result.

---

### document.evaluate()

[document.evaluate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) returns an [XPathResult](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XPathResult) based on an [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) expression and other given parameters.

The syntax is:

```
var xpathResult = document.evaluate(
  xpathExpression,
  contextNode,
  namespaceResolver,
  resultType,
  result
);
```

Where:

- `xpathExpression`: The string representing the XPath to be evaluated.
- `contextNode`: Specifies the context node for the query. Common practice is to pass `document` as the context node.
- `namespaceResolver`: The function that will be passed any namespace prefixes and should return a string representing the namespace URI associated with that prefix. It will be used to resolve prefixes within the XPath itself, so that they can be matched with the document. `null` is common for HTML documents or when no namespace prefixes are used.
- `resultType`: An integer that corresponds to the type of result XPathResult to return using [named constant properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate#Result_types), such as `XPathResult.ANY_TYPE`, of the XPathResult constructor, which correspond to integers from 0 to 9.
- `result`: An existing XPathResult to use for the results. `null` is the most common and will create a new XPathResult

---

### Demonstration

As an example the *Search Box* within the [Google Home Page](https://www.google.com/) which can be identified uniquely using the *xpath* as `//*[@name='q']` can also be identified using the [google-chrome-devtools](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools) *Console* by the following command:

```
$x("//*[@name='q']")
```

Snapshot:

[image: googlesearchbox_xpath]

The same element can can also be identified using `document.evaluate()` and the *xpath* expression as follows:

```
document.evaluate("//*[@name='q']", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
```

Snapshot:

[image: document_evalute_xpath]

Answer (score 31):

For something like $x from chrome command line api (to select multiple elements) try:

```
var xpath = function(xpathToExecute){
  var result = [];
  var nodesSnapshot = document.evaluate(xpathToExecute, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );
  for ( var i=0 ; i < nodesSnapshot.snapshotLength; i++ ){
    result.push( nodesSnapshot.snapshotItem(i) );
  }
  return result;
}
```

This MDN overview helped: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript

Answer (score 16):

Although many browsers have `$x(xPath)` as a console built-in, here's an aggregation of the useful-but-hardcoded snippets from [Introduction to using XPath in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript) ready for use in scripts:

### Snapshot

This gives a one-off snapshot of the xpath result set. Data may be stale after DOM mutations.

```js
const $x = xp => {
  const snapshot = document.evaluate(
    xp, document, null, 
    XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null
  );
  return [...Array(snapshot.snapshotLength)]
    .map((_, i) => snapshot.snapshotItem(i))
  ;
};

console.log($x('//h2[contains(., "foo")]'));
```

```html
<h2>foo</h2>
<h2>foobar</h2>
<h2>bar</h2>
```

### First ordered node

```js
const $xOne = xp => 
  document.evaluate(
    xp, document, null,
    XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null
  ).singleNodeValue
;

console.log($xOne('//h2[contains(., "foo")]'));
```

```html
<h2>foo</h2>
<h2>foobar</h2>
<h2>bar</h2>
```

### Iterator

> Note however, that if the document is mutated (the document tree is modified) between iterations that will invalidate the iteration and the `invalidIteratorState` property of `XPathResult` is set to `true`, and a `NS_ERROR_DOM_INVALID_STATE_ERR` exception is thrown.

```js
function *$xIter(xp) {
  const iter = document.evaluate(
    xp, document, null, 
    XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null
  );

  for (;;) {
    const node = iter.iterateNext();
    
    if (!node) {
      break;
    }
    
    yield node;
  }
}

// dump to array
console.log([...$xIter('//h2[contains(., "foo")]')]);

// return next item from generator
const xpGen = $xIter('//h2[text()="foo"]');
console.log(xpGen.next().value);
```

```html
<h2>foo</h2>
<h2>foobar</h2>
<h2>bar</h2>
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use javascript's [document.evaluate](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#XPathEvaluator-evaluate) to run an XPath expression on the DOM. I think it's supported in one way or another in browsers back to IE 6.

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate

IE supports [*selectNodes*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754523(v=vs.85).aspx) instead.

MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754523(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I'd like to note that {document.evaluate} does not work in IE.

Answer (score 7):

To direct to the point, you can easily use xpath. The exact and simple way to do this using the below code. Kindly try and provide feedback. Thank you.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

    //To click an element 
    WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath(Xpath));
    js.executeScript(("arguments[0].click();", element);
    
    //To gettext
    
    String theTextIWant = (String) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].value;",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='display-name']")));
```

Further readings -
https://medium.com/@smeesheady/webdriver-javascriptexecutor-interact-with-elements-and-open-and-handle-multiple-tabs-and-get-url-dcfda49bfa0f

Comment: I believe the OP didn't ask for a Selenium solution like yours, correct?

Comment: @ankostis It mentions "Selenium webdriver" in the title.

Comment: @mlen the original title had no such then - it wasbadded later.

Comment: @ankostis That's a funny way of apologizing for a snarky comment that was wrong.

Comment: The original post body had Selenium mentioned, so it's always been a part of the question. Titles tend to miss important details that eventually get hoisted from the body to improve SEO.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your objective is to develop and test your xpath queries for screen maps.  Then either use [Chrome's developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview#access).  This allows you to run the xpath query to show the matches.  Or in Firefox >9 you can do the same thing with the [Web Developer Tools console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Web_Console).  In earlier version use [x-path-finder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/xpath-finder/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Answer (score 2):

```
public class JSElementLocator {

    @Test
    public void locateElement() throws InterruptedException{
        WebDriver driver = WebDriverProducerFactory.getWebDriver("firefox");

        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");


        WebElement searchbox = null;

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        searchbox = (WebElement) (((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.getElementById('lst-ib');", searchbox));
        searchbox.sendKeys("hello");
    }
}
```

Make sure you are using the right locator for it.

Comment: Hi Prerit, the question was to select by an element based on its xpath. The solution you have provided is to select it by the id. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
**Different way to Find Element:**

IEDriver.findElement(By.id("id"));
IEDriver.findElement(By.linkText("linkText"));
IEDriver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath"));

IEDriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='id']"));
IEDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'button name')]"));
IEDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'text name')]"));
IEDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(.,'label name')]"));

IEDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'your text')]");

Check Case Sensitive:
IEDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(lower-case(text()),'your text')]");

For exact match: 
IEDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='your text']");

**Find NG-Element:**

Xpath == //td[contains(@ng-show,'childsegment.AddLocation')]
CssSelector == .sprite.icon-cancel
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path of your chrome exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='UserName']")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='UserName']")).sendKeys(Email);
```

Comment: add a descriptive answer. your description will help questioner to understand your solution quickly.