# Javascript to get hidden text value from website using Selenium web driver

Tags: javascript, selenium

How can i get this telefoon nummer in string variable.

```
<span itemprop="telephone" class="hidden" id="telefoon_28836_hidden">010 - 79 53 364</span>
```

I tried this code without ant success.

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 String script = "return   document.getElementByXPath('//span[@itemprop='telephone']').getText();";
 String telno1 = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script).toString();
```

I am getting this exception for String telno1 line

```
ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: missing ) after argument list
```

please any help thank you

Answer (score 6):

You can use this,

```
String theTextIWant = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].value;",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@itemprop='telephone']")));
```

You just use javascript to extract out the value attribute of the input field. If it were a div or textarea, then you'd like use the innerHTML, innerText, or textContent attributes. like below,

```
String theTextIWant = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@itemprop='telephone']")));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing a number of things here. You cannot just copy/paste Selenium code and expect it to work in JavaScript.

My suggestion would be to be to *first* find the element using Selenium's XPath mechanism, and *then* pass that into a JavaScript string. You are merely working *against* Selenium's API because it allows you to find elements in variety of ways and it will transform that into an object that can be used in JavaScript **for you** if you want to.

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@itemprop='telephone']"));
jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].text", element);
```

(Untested, unverified code, I do not have a Java IDE to handle, may not compile)

Answer (score 1):

The inner xpath string does not seems to be formed properly. This is because of the 'Single Quotes' used:

Try replacing:

```
String script = "return   document.getElementByXPath('//span[@itemprop='telephone']').getText();";
```

With:

```
String script = "return   document.getElementByXPath(\"//span[@itemprop='telephone']\").getText();";
                                                      ^                              ^
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion i just tried but now i am getting document.getElementByXPath is not a function error

Comment: Have you defined any 'getElementByXpath' function? I think there isn't any OTB function named 'getElementByXpath'.
If you are using Selenium for JS (WebDriverJS), then they have other functions defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
driver.findElement(By.id("telefoon_28836_hidden")).getText();
```

If works, let us know.

Answer (score 0):

This will cause error: `document.getElementByXPath is not a function`

Use `document.evaluate` insteads. Answer of **yckart** in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596417/is-there-a-way-to-get-element-by-xpath-using-javascript-in-selenium-webdriver) is helpful.

Hope this helps!