# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I am working on selenium webdriver and I need to enter text without using sendkeys method, because the search popup text field is hidden. So I wrote below code:

1st way:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementByXpath('//input[@class='form-control input-small input-inline']').value='TextValue'");
```

2nd Way:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
//jse.executeScript("document.getElementByXpath('//input[@class='form-control input-small input-inline']').value ='abcd';");
```

3rd way:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].type ='search';",chemObject.getSearchPopup());
```

but I am getting syntax error as I mentioned in the title.

Comment: can you please add your HTML code of that element and its parents

Answer (score 7):

Your first one is producing the JavaScript error, and the reason is mixed-up single quotes, which you wouldn't have seen from the Java code, not until the JS was executed.

The simplest fix is to replace:

`((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementByXpath('//input[@class='form-control input-small input-inline']').value='TextValue'");`

with:

`((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementByXpath(\"//input[@class='form-control input-small input-inline']\").value='TextValue'");`

However, it still won't work for you (nor your second attempt), because `getElementByXpath` isn't a JavaScript DOM method.

This is all covered in a [very similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21909868/954442) here.

Comment: Hi, please "accept" this answer (green tick) if it helped you solve your problem - thanks!