# Selenium : Enter the text in div using xpath

Tags: java, selenium

In selenium for inputbox, we can enter value like :

```
WebElement inputBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)));
inputBox.sendKeys("abc");
```

but on 1 webpage, I am having one button after clicking on that get one div in which i have to enter through selenium, I am getting the xpath for that div like

```
WebElement inputDiv = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'x-grid3-cell-inner')]"));
inputDiv.sendKeys("abc");           //This is not working
```

using xpath,I am getting the div, But how to enter text in that using it's xpath?

Html after adding the text manually :

```
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner">ty</div>
```

The div in which I have to enter the text is:

```
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner" />
```

Comment: You need to provide the full html for that text input. Sometimes you will need to get a handle on the input that is contained by the div.

Comment: There is not input box, I have to enter in the div directly. and using sendKeys I am not able to

Comment: Can you provide the html you are targeting? It's hard to help with the information provided.

Comment: Updated the question, Can you please look into this now ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update the DIV text using JavaScript

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('Div_Id').innerHTML="+ DesiredText);
```

Using XPATH in JavaScript

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.evaluate(xpathExpresion, document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue.innerHTML="+ DesiredText);
```

[**Reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596417/is-there-a-way-to-get-element-by-xpath-in-javascript)

Comment: Any option by using xpath. I can only xpath for that.As id is auto generated.

Comment: Note the XPath JS solution you've got isn't going to work in <IE9

Comment: So any other solution for this ?

Comment: @iRunner Which browser you are using?

Comment: Currently Firefox. but may have to automate using IE.

Comment: I am using this executor.executeScript("document.evaluate('//div[contains(@class,'x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-code')]', document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue.innerHTML="+ "abc");   It is giving me error as Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: missing ) after argument list Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit this div using send keys as it has no Input to send to. Instead, try and edit the text field of the div.

Comment: Any suggestions how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Sendkeys is used to type in the input field with tag name 'input'
You cannot use sendkeys here

Rather you will have to use JavascriptExecutorto do this

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('Div_Id').innerHTML="+ DesiredText);
```