# SeleniumIDE can type text only into input field?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I try to check the sending tweets (twitter.com) using seleniumIDE, but I ran into a problem. Textbox for tweets - div element. SeleniumIDE allows to write text only into `input` element? I tried to use the `type id=tweet-box-home-timeline test tweet` command, but it does not work. Which command should I use to write text into a div?
[image]

[image]

Comment: no, can I somehow enter the text in area for tweets?

Answer (score 1):

The below is working for me. This is after you have logged in.

```
<tr>
     <td>clickAt</td>
     <td>xpath=(//div[@id='tweet-box-home-timeline'])</td>
     <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>storeEval</td>
     <td>selenium.browserbot.findElement(&quot;tweet-box-home-timeline&quot;).innerHTML='The Lord is my shepherd I shall not want he leads me';</td>
     <td>myval</td>
</tr>
<tr>
      <td>click</td>
      <td>xpath=(//button[@class='btn primary-btn tweet-action tweet-btn js-tweet-btn'])</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best I could manage was manipulating it via java script:

```
document.getElementById("tweet-box-home-timeline").innerHTML='abc';
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775924/selenium-enter-the-text-in-div-using-xpath seems to indicate that sendKeys will only work with input box...

Answer (score -1):

You better use Java, Selenium IDE isn't useful tool. 
I've tested Selenium IDE with twitter fields, unfortunately it doesn't work.

It works for me:

```
    driver.get("https://twitter.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("signin-email")).sendKeys("YOUR LOGIN");
    driver.findElement(By.id("signin-password")).sendKeys("YOUR PASSWORD");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='submit btn primary-btn flex-table-btn js-submit']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("tweet-box-home-timeline")).sendKeys("Test");
```

Give it a try.

Comment: While it's true that java implementation of webdriver does give the user a lot more control to call the IDE not useful is just an inflammatory statement.