# Unable to replace value in a table column

Tags: java, selenium, settext

Unable to send values in the table column. I got different errors while I am trying to insert a value in the column using Selenium.

1. I tried to set a new value in the table's column. It shows the error as The element must be user-editable in order to clear it.

   ```
   WebElement.clear();
   WebElement.sendKeys("value");

     (or)

   WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
   WebElement.sendKeys("value");
   ```
2. Then to click and edit the value.

   ```
   Actions actions = new Actions(getWebDriverEx());
   WebElement TableColumn = Driver.findElement(By.id("element"));
   actions.moveToElement(TableColumn);
   actions.click().build().perform();
   actions.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE+b+b);
   actions.sendKeys("value");
   ```

   The value which was passed is not inserted in the Tables column. But I can able to click the Tables column. Here my test passed.
3. Then tried to set value. It shows the error as timed out.

   ```
    WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
    WebElement.sendKeys("15000");
   ```
4. Again I used the div/span combination as XPath and I have edited the value. But it does not reflect in the table.

   ```
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
   js.executeScript("document.getElementById('element').innerHTML="+15000);
   ```

Here I do not get any errors. But the value not reflected after save.

I gave element to various formats.

1. div//[id]
2. div//span
3. XPath
4. id alone (which was in the div)

HTML:

```
<div id="element" class="tables_second_column">
    <div class="class_name">
        <div class="class_name">
            <div class="class_name"><span>5000</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First 3 approaches are not correct as sendKeys works only on 'input' html elements like textbox and textarea, not for span and div. In the fourth approach you need to get to the span and then use innerhtml. -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775924/selenium-enter-the-text-in-div-using-xpath

Comment: @Grasshopper But why to resort to `JavascriptExecutor` without a fair trial with `Java` **`click()`**?

Comment: @DebanjanB It is not mentioned if clicking makes a textbox to be visible to enter text. If so then it should be the preferred method.

Comment: @Grasshopper I don't see any reason for the `textbox` to be `invisible` or `hidden`. IMO, as you mentioned OP simply didn't go deeper into the `<span>` tag. So my guess `Java click()` should work.

Comment: @Grasshopper, `sendKeys` is not limited to any type of HTML element and a `<DIV>` can become editable by setting the attribute [`contenteditable="true"`](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content$samples/How_does_it_work?revision=1323330).

Comment: @FlorentB. Did not know that... Thx

Comment: @DebanjanB Java click() was working. But for my scenario, I want to pass the value in the table column. After the click, I can't able to pass the value. Again it shows the error as focus the element

Comment: @Jes, was my answer useful? If yes -- check a tick near my answer, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply

It works for me with the below method

```
webElement.sendKeysByAction(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the `HTML` you shared, the table column is within a **`<span>`** which is inside several `<div>` tags. Hence we need to construct an unique **`xpath`** to identify the **`WebElement`** and first send **`clear()`** method then use **`sendKeys()`** method as follows :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='element']/div[@class='class_name']/div[@class='class_name']/div[@class='class_name']/span[text()='5000']")).clear();    
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='element']/div[@class='class_name']/div[@class='class_name']/div[@class='class_name']/span[text()='5000']")).sendKeys("15000");
```

### Update

As you mentioned `Text which was passed in the span is not predictable` so we would simply omit the clause `[text()='5000']`. As you have provided a sample `HTML` with sample `classnames` I have constructed a nearly absolute `xpath`. So our code will be :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='element']/div[@class='class_name']/div[@class='class_name']/div[@class='class_name']/span")).clear();    
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='element']/div[@class='class_name']/div[@class='class_name']/div[@class='class_name']/span")).sendKeys("15000");
```

Comment: Text which was passed in the span is not predictable. It is a dynamic value. I need to get the text before passing the sendKeys.

Comment: Check out my updated Answer and let me know the status

Comment: Unable to clear the webelement and it shows the error as "Element must be user-editable in order to clear it"

Comment: So that means the **sample [DIV]** s which you have provided on your own is uneditable and incorrect & we can't help you in that. So please `Accept` the `Answer` by clicking on the tick mark beside my **`Answer`**, just below the `VoteDown` arrow, so the tick mark turns Green.

Comment: Div is correct. Using the XPath which you have mentioned above not working for me.  I need to get the element first. Then only I can able to edit the value.

Answer (score 1):

Try on the following and it's working for me:

```
js = "document.querySelector('#element .class_name .class_name .class_name>span').innerHTML = '15000';"
driver.execute_script(js)
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

This should be sufficient

```
WebElement textBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='5000']"));
textBox.clear();
textBox.sendKeys("");
textBox.sendKeys("15000");
```

I do send a empty space in order to get the textbox active as sometime the DOM might not reflect immediately as this element is quiet nested.