# How to enter text in a DIV with python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, input

## How to enter text in a DIV with python selenium

---

### Background-Info

I'm trying to create a bot to leave comments on various TikTok posts, some of these posts will need to leave a mention ex.`@username`. The issue is, that the comment box for TikTok is a `div` element and not an `input` element.

---

### What I've tried

- So first of all I am aware of [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775924/selenium-enter-the-text-in-div-using-xpath), to some it up it just says to use javascript to update the div values. The issue with this is that if you edit the code it will not show the drop-down menu of usernames

**What is the 'drop-down menu of usernames'?**

This is the little menu that goes down with suggestions of the user your trying to mention

For example, if I type "@userna" it will show many users with usernames similar

Like this
[image]

- To verify this I tried editing the `span` in inspect element and it wouldn't show the drop-down menu. Which I believe is the same thing as editing the div with javascript. (the comment box is a `div` but the text inside is a `span`)

This is the XPath for the comment box

```
//div[@class='DraftEditor-root']
```

- I've tried clicking the div with  (worked)

```py
# get comment box
comment_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='DraftEditor-root']")

# click the comment box
CommentBox = ActionChains(driver).click(comment_box).perform()
```

Then I tried to just send keys to the driver thinking it would just type and fill in anything selected like this  (didn't work)

```py
CommentBox = ActionChains(driver).send_keys('@test')
```

---

### This is the full HTML code for the comment box

```html
<div data-e2e="comment-input" class="tiktok-1vwgyq9-DivInputAreaContainer e1npxakq2">
    <div data-e2e="comment-text" class="tiktok-qpucp9-DivInputEditorContainer e1npxakq3">
        <div class="tiktok-ybf3r7-DivInputAreaContainer e12pqyqm0">
            <div class="DraftEditor-root">
                <div class="public-DraftEditorPlaceholder-root">
                    <div class="public-DraftEditorPlaceholder-inner" id="placeholder-24b80" style="white-space: pre-wrap;">Add comment...</div>
                </div>
                <div class="DraftEditor-editorContainer">
                    <div class="notranslate public-DraftEditor-content" contenteditable="true" role="textbox" spellcheck="false" aria-describedby="placeholder-24b80" style="outline: none; -webkit-user-select: text; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word;">
                        <div data-contents="true">
                            <div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="24b80" data-offset-key="eap17-0-0">
                                <div data-offset-key="eap17-0-0" class="public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr">
                                    <span data-offset-key="eap17-0-0">
                                        <br data-text="true">
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-e2e="comment-at-icon" class="tiktok-1vi8qz3-DivMentionButton e1npxakq4">
        <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M24 6C14.0589 6 6 14.0589 6 24C6 33.9411 14.0589 42 24 42C28.0553 42 31.7921 40.6614 34.8006 38.401L35.6001 37.8003C36.0416 37.4686 36.6685 37.5576 37.0003 37.9992L38.2016 39.5981C38.5334 40.0397 38.4443 40.6666 38.0028 40.9983L37.2033 41.599C33.5258 44.3619 28.9513 46 24 46C11.8497 46 2 36.1503 2 24C2 11.8497 11.8497 2 24 2C36.1503 2 46 11.8497 46 24V26C46 30.4843 42.1949 34 37.8438 34C35.1966 34 32.8496 32.7142 31.3935 30.733C29.5649 32.7403 26.9303 34 24 34C18.4772 34 14 29.5228 14 24C14 18.4772 18.4772 14 24 14C29.5228 14 34 18.4772 34 24C34 24.5814 33.9502 25.1528 33.8541 25.7096C33.8473 25.8052 33.8438 25.902 33.8438 26C33.8438 28.2091 35.6347 30 37.8438 30C40.1201 30 42 28.1431 42 26V24C42 14.0589 33.9411 6 24 6ZM24 18C20.6863 18 18 20.6863 18 24C18 27.3137 20.6863 30 24 30C26.9395 30 29.3891 27.8841 29.9013 25.0918C29.9659 24.7392 30 24.3744 30 24C30 20.6863 27.3137 18 24 18Z"></path>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div data-e2e="comment-emoji-icon" class="tiktok-1yq6goo-DivEmojiButton e1npxakq5">
        <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M24 6C14.0589 6 6 14.0589 6 24C6 33.9411 14.0589 42 24 42C33.9411 42 42 33.9411 42 24C42 14.0589 33.9411 6 24 6ZM2 24C2 11.8497 11.8497 2 24 2C36.1503 2 46 11.8497 46 24C46 36.1503 36.1503 46 24 46C11.8497 46 2 36.1503 2 24Z"></path><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M17 23C18.6569 23 20 21.2091 20 19C20 16.7909 18.6569 15 17 15C15.3431 15 14 16.7909 14 19C14 21.2091 15.3431 23 17 23Z"></path>
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M31 23C32.6569 23 34 21.2091 34 19C34 16.7909 32.6569 15 31 15C29.3431 15 28 16.7909 28 19C28 21.2091 29.3431 23 31 23Z"></path>
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M16 28.3431C16 31.4673 19.5817 36 24 36C28.4183 36 32 31.4673 32 28.3431C32 25.219 16 25.219 16 28.3431Z"></path>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the right div? I couldn't check myself without a ticktock account, but try to enter sometext, then inspect the page to see where your text is updated

Comment: @liorbakalo the text is updated with a span, I put all the HTML for the page above, But I'm assuming I have to type text to the DIV because if i click the DIV with selenium it selects it

Comment: Ok, thanks for the details I'll try to help. Can you set any text in that div at all? (Meaning is it a tagging problem only, or a problem of inserting text to comment in general)

Comment: Well the span holds the text and yes @liorbakalo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you adress the container div instead of the span. Unfortantly I can't test it as I don't have a tiktok account. Hopfully this solutions will help, or at list rule out this possability.

### Solutions:

1. Click the span instead of the div, then send keys.

Alternatively

2. **Programeticly add text to the span**

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

// Choose the desired span, and add your text into it
js.executeScript("document.quarySelectorAll('[data-offset-key]')[0].innerHTML= @userName");

// try setting focus on the span to active the popup list
js.executeScript("document.quarySelectorAll('[data-offset-key]')[0].focus()")

// try setting a change event on the span to active the popup list
js.executeScript("document.quarySelectorAll('[data-offset-key]')[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { 'bubbles': true }))")
```

Comment: I lowkey love you for this