# DOM find element by Xpath

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm new to DOM querying and I'm wondering if it is possible to query DOM elements directly by Xpath in a similar way to the below-mentioned code?

```
document.getElementById("searchInput");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, XPath can do that. `//*[@id='searchInput']`

Comment: Thanks, so I would just pass the Xpath as a parameter to the getElementById method?

Comment: @user3648426 no. thats the equivalent xpath.

Comment: no. gEBI has nothing to do with xpath. xpath is a general purpose dom tree querying tool. gEBI is a very very specific search, and *may* use xpath internally, but probably doesn't for efficiency.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to get element by XPath using JavaScript in Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596417/is-there-a-way-to-get-element-by-xpath-using-javascript-in-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 8):

The equivalent statement using only XPath would be

```
xPathResult = document.evaluate('//*[@id="searchInput"]', document);
if(xPathResult){
     element = xPathResult.iterateNext();
}
```

Have a look at the [Intro to XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript) in the browser on MDN for some more examples and usages.

Comment: unlike `$x('...')` this works

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for one or the first element behind your XPath, you can use this one liner:

```
const yourstring = "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/h3";
const element = document.evaluate(yourstring, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,null).singleNodeValue;
```