# DOM Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined

Tags: javascript

There is an element i am trying to gain access to deep inside the DOM.

So,i navigated the DOM to reach that element with the following code.

```
    var body = document.body;
    var bodychild5 = body.children[5];
    var container = bodychild5.children[0];
    var mainright = container.children[1];
    var rbslip = mainright.children[1];
    var slip = rbslip.children[1];
    var sliplayer = slip.children[3];
    var innerpadding = sliplayer.children[1];
    var bsbody = innerpadding.children[0];
    var formclass = bsbody.children[0];
    var gslip = formclass.children[0];
    var almostinput = gslip.children[8];
    var input = almostinput.children[1];
```

I got the element but when i run the code,i get an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined when it gets to gslip.

Comment: probably the document hasn't finished loading  yet, so add an event handler for `window.addEventListener('load', function() { /* your code here */ })`

Comment: @Icepickle,your code worked.

Answer (score 0):

Node `bsbody` likely has no child nodes.

a) better add `id` / `class` attributes, in order to instead use `document.getElementById()` or `document.getElementsByClassName()`.

b) This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24270377/549372) demonstrates, how to select nodes by their `xpath` (which one can be copied from the `F12` tools of the web-browser).

Comment: ~bsbody.children[0]~ has childnodes i took time to inspect it,it does have children.

Comment: @IvakaZakuri `Cannot read property 'children' of undefined` means that there is something `typeof "undefined"`... which means that the previous assignment do not catch any node. You're vastly over-complicating a simple problem by using 13 instructions, for something that needs 1 single instruction. for example: `console.debug(document.getElementById('answer-57564618'));`.

Comment: ,i found the problem.The problem is,the document hasn't finished loading.