# TypeError: $ is not a function in selenium java during html5 dragdrop

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

**Problem Statement:** dragdrop function from selenium java class returns an exception **org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: TypeError: $ is not a function**

In few forums it was suggested to use js available in below location to perform html5 dragdrop in selenium java and followed same steps but resulted in above error.

Selenium 3.141
Chrome 76

drag_drop_function is defined in drag_drop_helper.js as below

js reference: https://gist.github.com/rcorreia/2362544#file-drag_and_drop_helper-js

```
(function($){
        $.fn.simulateDragDrop = function(options) {
                return this.each(function() {
                        new $.simulateDragDrop(this, options);
                });
        };
        $.simulateDragDrop = function(elem, options) {
                this.options = options;
                this.simulateEvent(elem, options);
        };
        $.extend($.simulateDragDrop.prototype, {
                simulateEvent: function(elem, options) {
                        /*Simulating drag start*/
                        var type = 'dragstart';
                        var event = this.createEvent(type);
                        this.dispatchEvent(elem, type, event);

                        /*Simulating drop*/
                        type = 'drop';
                        var dropEvent = this.createEvent(type, {});
                        dropEvent.dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer;
                        this.dispatchEvent($(options.dropTarget)[0], type, dropEvent);

                        /*Simulating drag end*/
                        type = 'dragend';
                        var dragEndEvent = this.createEvent(type, {});
                        dragEndEvent.dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer;
                        this.dispatchEvent(elem, type, dragEndEvent);
                },
                createEvent: function(type) {
                        var event = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
                        event.initCustomEvent(type, true, true, null);
                        event.dataTransfer = {
                                data: {
                                },
                                setData: function(type, val){
                                        this.data[type] = val;
                                },
                                getData: function(type){
                                        return this.data[type];
                                }
                        };
                        return event;
                },
                dispatchEvent: function(elem, type, event) {
                        if(elem.dispatchEvent) {
                                elem.dispatchEvent(event);
                        }else if( elem.fireEvent ) {
                                elem.fireEvent("on"+type, event);
                        }
                }
        });
})(jQuery);
```

Below lines of code read js file and trigger html5 dragdrop function defined in js file

```
 String js_filepath = "C:/test/drag_and_drop_helper.js";
           String java_script = "";
           String text;
           BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(js_filepath));
           StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
           while ((text = input.readLine()) != null)
                buffer.append(text + " ");
                java_script = buffer.toString();

WebElement source1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.object-card-value[title=test]"));
WebElement dest1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[data-field-name='references']"));

 java_script = java_script + "$(arguments[0]).simulateDragDrop({dropTarget:arguments[1]});";
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(java_script, source1, dest1);
```

Result:
Elements are identified properly and js file is read as well but fails to trigger dragdrop with an error **TypeError: $ is not a function**

**Status 1:**

@pcalkins Thank you. I tried as per your suggesstion but no drag drop action happens on both chrome and FF browsers.

Only difference is I'm trying to pass using css selector as I dont have id. todrag and todrop elements are getting highlighted properly. No exceptions are thrown, but drag drop action doesn't happen.

```
 var toDrag =document.querySelectorAll(\"span.object-card-value[title='test']\"); var toDrop = document.querySelectorAll(\" div[data-field-name='references']\");";
 ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(simulateFunction + "simulateDragDrop(toDrag, toDrop);"); //also tried with queryselector
```

**Update2** markup as below

drag markup

```
<ul class="object-list drop-target"> changes to object-list drop-target active drag-over, drag-over triggers?
        <li class="chooser add"><div class="autocomplete">
        <div class="autocomplete-searchbox" tabindex="1">
            <input placeholder="Drop here " class="autocomplete-input autocomplete-single-select form-control" size="30" style="width: 100%;" type="text">
            <span class="autocomplete-reset fonticon fonticon-clear"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="autocomplete-suggests">
        <div class="autocomplete-suggests-scroll  scroller scroller-root" style="overflow: hidden;">
        <div class="no-native-scrollbars  scroller-content" style="right: -16px; bottom: -16px; padding-right: 16px; padding-bottom: 16px;">
        <ul tabindex="1" class="scroller-shift">
            </ul></div></div></div></div>
        <button class="btn"><span class="fonticon fonticon-search"></span></button></li>

        <li class="object-card has-image" data-field-name="item" data-type="Document" data-id="16C31E069B1C00009555C15DB7CC0B00" data-hasfiles="TRUE">
             <span class="draggable-item" draggable="true">
                <span class="thumbnail object-image">
                   <img draggable="false" oncontextmenu="return false" src="http://test.com" title="test">
                </span>
            <span data-field-name="display-value"><span class="object-card-value" oncontextmenu="return false" title="test" style="background: yellow; border: 2px solid red;">test</span></span>
            </span>
            <span class="actions">
                <button class="btn">
                    <span class="fonticon fonticon-down-open" data-field-name="deliverables" title=""></span>
                </button>
            </span>
        </li>

 WebElement source1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.object-card-value[title='test']"));
```

drop markup

```
<div id="card0">
<div class="card-content" data-id="16C31E069B1C00008B21C15D91F10B00" oncontextmenu="return false">
      <div class="card-title">Context</div>
      <div class="card-properties">
            <div class="card-details ">
                  <div class="thumbnail type">
                        <span class="task"></span>
 </div></div></div></div></div></div>    

 WebElement dest1 = driver.findElement(By.id("card0"));
```

As soon as user moves drag element, a drag-over event seem to be triggered, which changes **object-list drop-target** to `object-list drop-target drag-over`

Comment: Is jQuery being referenced in the web page you are testing? If not, then this solution will not help you. If jQuery is being pulled in, it might be a race condition between Selenium and the browser downloading and parsing the jQuery.js file.

Comment: See my answer here for non-prototype version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56604135/why-this-seleniums-drag-and-drop-c-sharp-code-is-not-working-on-chrome/56615037#56615037

Comment: @pcalkins can you please review my updated comments under 'status' and let me know your view.

Comment: @GregBurghardt It is not referenced in web page and as you have mentioned I'm trying to inject jquery using jquery_load_helper.js  (reference: https://github.com/ArturSpirin/YouTube-WebDriver-Tutorials/tree/master/drag_and_drop)

Comment: @GregBurghardt I changed $ to jQuery and don't see typeError exception but dragdrop doesn't happen. I see error in console as -- JavaScript error: https://tesas.com/webapps/commonUI.js?v=20191029T194021Z, line 1: TypeError: z is undefined.

Comment: I think SelectorAll returns an array... post the markup.

Comment: @pcalkins please find my markup under 'update 1' header. I also tried with just selector but not useful. Please let me know if anything is missed.

Comment: I meant the HTML markup showing the drag elements and event handlers.

Comment: not real sure if those escaped quotes will work there... you should probably also find/wait for those elements first.  (In normal Java/Selenium... before the executeScript call)  Use the same selectors in your webdriverwaits.  This script creates certain events that Selenium doesn't yet support.  You may or may not need them... it depends on the markup/event handlers.

Comment: @pcalkins Thank you. Please find my update2 and see if it is helpful. I noticed a drag-over event getting triggered as soon as draggable element is dragged and the same event seem to be missing in javascript snippet. I tried escaping slashes and with wait but no action happened.

Comment: ok, (no event handlers there) but draggable element is this:   <span class="draggable-item" draggable="true">  (I don't think spans are draggable by default) So that's not a lot to go by... if there's more than one draggable item, it may be a complicated xpath to get to the specific one you are targetting.  You need the parent span of the parent span of the span that contains text of "test".  It looks like this is in a test state, so the writers of the markup/script should add an ID to the draggable which is unique.  Otherwise try to write a selector that gets the parent-parent span to drag.

Comment: still need the event handlers... the script you are using creates dragstart, drop and dragend events.  If this site's script works on other events, you need another approach.

Comment: see here for xpath call using native javascript:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24270101/dom-find-element-by-xpath  Assuming you can escape those quotes the answer here is what you may want to use to get the element.

Comment: @pcalkins tried with xpath based on the link shared but no success. Is there a way to add drag-over event to the existing javascript.

Comment: @pcalkins  I tried executing same code on https://jqueryui.com/droppable/ and I see similar behavior, drag element gets highlighted but no action happens. Firefox browser is getting launched and also navigated properly but unable to dragdrop.

Comment: ok, for that page you CAN use Selenium actions to perform the drag.... something like  this:   int xtarget = 150;
   int ytarget = 0; WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(//div[@id="draggable"]));
  Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.dragAndDropBy(element, xtarget, ytarget).perform();

Comment: jQuery supports non-HTML5 browsers, so it uses the old-school events to perform drag/drop.

Comment: you should also be able to use actions.dragAndDrop(dragWebElement, dropWebElement);  See: https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#dragAndDrop-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-

Comment: @pcalkins i thought jqueryui link is an html5 example and want to cross-check whether js enabled solution dragdrop works. Thank you for actions based snippet.

Comment: @pcalkins w.r.to earlier issue related to dragdrop which we have been discussing works ok with combination of action and robot class but it has a dependency on co-ordinates and doesn't work on chrome. So thought of avoiding these two dependency using any other solution which seem to be still not working for our application after many trials.

Comment: robot class shouldn't be necessary... just remember if you are using dragAndDropTo, that it's an offset from the draggable's current position.  So 100 x value is 100 pixels to the right... negative is to the left, etc...  that could present a problem in different resolutions, though.