# SetProperty Is undefined for XMLdocument

Tags: javascript, xml

So there is this piece of code that is causing me problems in IE 11 and chrome too. I am not sure what is happening since it should be working,  this is old code I am helping fix, but it looks good to me. I am creating an xml document object and calling the setproperty method, but it is saying that the function is undefined. This is what my code looks like

```
if (window.DOMParser) {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
    } else {
        xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = false;
        xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);
    }        
    console.log(xmlDoc);
    console.log(typeof xmlDoc.setProperty);
```

and the result of the `console.log`

[image]

Anybody knows what is happening?

Comment: What makes you think you can call `setProperty` on an XML document?  None of IE11, Firefox and Chrome appears to support this method.  What is the code that calls `setProperty` trying to achieve?

Comment: @LukeWoodward not really sure either, something about setting the language for xpath `xmlDoc.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setProperty` method you mention belongs to  [an `ActiveXObject` used to parse XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760290(v=vs.85).aspx).  There is no such method on the XML document returned by the `DOMParser`, and this is why you are getting the error in browsers that support `DOMParser`.

If you want to use XPath to query XML in JavaScript, I would recommend using `document.evaluate` instead.  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596417/).