# Scroll to element with specific text contents

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

In the page I have time and right of it some pictures. I wanna to create a button to jump to current time using Tampermonkey. Current time is a text in `<h1>`. You can see a screenshot below.
[image: time screen]

[image: code screen]

How to jump to some position. For example 07:39.
If you want to suggest external library, please show me how to use it in Tampermonkey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Finding H1 by XPath

If the document tree is stable (the order of elements is always the same) you can get the [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) and [get the H1 element by xPath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14284815/607407). That would be the fastest (in the mean of CPU time) solution.

### Finding H1 with time in it

Otherwise, I'd use regular expression to detect time format in H1 element.

```
var headers = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
//Regexp: Any amount of whitespace; One or two numbers; :; Two numbers; any ammount of whitespace
var check = /\s*[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}\s*/;
//Position
var pos = 0;
for(var i=0, l=headers.length;i<l;i++)
{
    if(check.test(headers[i].textContent))
    {
        pos = headers[i].offsetTop;
        //After finding the element, do not loop any more.
        break;
    }
}
//Scroll to pixel position [0; pos]
window.scrollTo(0,pos);
```

### Getting specific time and finding it

If you want to jump to as **specific time** (eg. current time at any moment), go for the [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). With that, you can do as follows:

```
var date = new Date();
var time_string = zeroFill(date.getHours())+":"+zeroFill(date.getMinutes());
//Procceed with the loop
```

Using the [zeroFill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1267392/607407) function.

Answer (score 0):

Seems my javascript experience grows :)

```
var myList = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
var time = "07:39";
for(var i=0;i<myList.length;i++)
{
    if(myList[i].textContent == time)
    {
        var pos = myList[i].offsetTop;
    }
}
window.scrollTo(0,pos);
```

Comment: Yeah. I use it with button. Its working only after page is fully loaded. I have no another solution for now :(

Comment: There are also some flaws to your code. First, you lack a `break` in your `for`, so it will loop even **after** finding the correct H1. Second, when no `H1` is found, you get an **undefined variable** error.

Comment: I tryed to use `window.onload = function ()` to test if  i pressed button before to load scroll again, but seems this functions not see my vars.

Comment: Variable only lasts in the function where it was defined. What about other way around? Define global variable `var loaded = false` and set it to true in the onload event.