# Select Nodes in XML

Tags: javascript, xml, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to select the value of a specific node `"effectiveintervalstart"` from the XML below (pasted all the way on the bottom since it's long).

Here's my code:

```js
//the XML is returned into req.responseXML.xml
var result = req.responseXML.xml.toString();
            var doc = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument");
            doc.async = false;
            doc.loadXML(result);

            var arrayAnswers = [];
            var arr = doc.selectNodes("//b:effectiveintervalstart");
            for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {

                arrayAnswers[i] = arr.nextNode.text;
            }

            alert(arrayAnswers);
            alert(arrayAnswers.length)
```

However so far this is returning an empty array instead.

This is my XML.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <RetrieveMultipleResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <RetrieveMultipleResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
        <a:Entities>
          <a:Entity>
        <a:Attributes xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>calendarid</b:key>
            <b:value i:type="c:guid" xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">933d2b7d-0e7c-e211-a14f-78e7d1620f84</b:value>
          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>calendarrules</b:key>
            <b:value i:type="a:EntityCollection">
              <a:Entities>
                <a:Entity>
                  <a:Attributes>
                    <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                      <b:key>calendarruleid</b:key>
                      <b:value i:type="c:guid" xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">b77b4621-3774-e411-80db-005056971aab</b:value>
                    </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>                        

                    /* this node */
                    <a:KeyValuePairOfstringstring>
                      <b:key>effectiveintervalstart</b:key>
                      <b:value>11/26/2014</b:value>
                    </a:KeyValuePairOfstringstring>
                    /*  */

                    <a:KeyValuePairOfstringstring>
                      <b:key>rank</b:key>
                      <b:value>0</b:value>
                    </a:KeyValuePairOfstringstring>
```

Thank you very much for your help, much appreciated. 
.

Comment: I'm guessing your error lie around var arr = doc.selectNodes("//b:effectiveintervalstart");
Try "/Envelope/Body/RetrieveMultipleResponse/RetrieveMultipleResult/Attributes/KeyValuePairOfStringanyType/Value/Entities/Entity/Attributes/KeyValuePairOfstringstring/"

Comment: Where do you see the node `b:effectiveintervalstart`, it doesn't exist... the node `//a:KeyValuePairOfstringstring[b:key = 'effectiveintervalstartdate']/b:value` does exist. You might want to take a look at the Sdk.Soap.js library for inspiration https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SdkSoapjs-9b51b99a.

Answer (score 0):

As @ThijsKuipers mentions, the ´MSXML.DOMDocument´ doesn't know about the namespaces (´a:´ and ´b:´) you are referencing.

You must make your DOM aware of the namespaces by adding:

```
//From: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SdkSoapjs-9b51b99a/sourcecode?fileId=113716&pathId=1614657476

var ns = { 
  "s": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", 
  "a": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts", 
  "i": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", 
  "b": "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic", 
  "c": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", 
  "d": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services", 
  "e": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/", 
  "f": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays", 
  "g": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2011/Contracts", 
  "h": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Metadata", 
  "j": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Metadata/Query", 
  "k": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2013/Metadata", 
  "l": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2012/Contracts" 
 }; 

var namespaces = []; 
for (var i in ns)
{ 
    namespaces.push("xmlns:" + i + "='" + ns[i] + "'"); 
} 

doc.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", namespaces.join(" "));
```

Then you can query your XML as you expect.

**Cross-browser support**

On a side note: You **shouldn't be using *new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")* at all**

Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Project Spartan and any other HTML5-only browser don't understand "ActiveXObject".
How do I then parse XML, you might ask? 
The before mentioned SoapJs uses document.evaluate. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596417/is-there-a-way-to-get-element-by-xpath-in-javascript) for details.

**OData**

If you by any means can rewrite you query to use the [OData endpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx) then it will/could return JSON back which, by nature, is much more JavaScript-friendly.