# options under dropdown menu is not getting selected

Tags: javascript, html-select, casperjs

Testing scenario is,

1. creating a cell,
2. Change the language from the drop down menu(from R to Python),
3. Enter the code and execute it. HTML code for drop down menu is

```
<select class="form-control cell-control-select cell-control">
    <option>Markdown</option>
    <option>R</option>
    <option>Python</option>
    <option>RMarkdown</option>
</select>
```

and below is my casperjs code

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.mouse.click({ type: 'xpath' , path: "/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/select"});//x path for dropdown menu
    this.echo('clicking on dropdown menu');
    this.wait(3000);
});

casper.then(function(){
    var z = this.evaluate(function() {
    document.querySelector('.form-control').selectedIndex = 2;
    return true;
    });
    this.wait(3000);
});
```

it is selecting the Python language from the drop down menu but when we run the code it is showing Error in prompt cell. The same error we get when we run R code in python language cell.

Comment: What's the error that you see? After you change the selected index, does it show that "Python" is selected when you take the screenshot? Is the select box maybe hidden and the actual dropdown is implemented with HTML+CSS+JS?

Comment: ya it is showing 'Python' in drop down menu. i am using just simple python code which is a=50;print a. when it gets execute (Python is selected in drop down), it is showing 'Parse error: <text>:1:12: unexpected symbol 1: a=50;print a' error. This error occurs when we run python code in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably that there is a change listener on the select box which doesn't get called, because setting the `selectedIndex` property doesn't trigger a change.

A reliable way to trigger this change is to use [jQuery's `change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/):

```
this.evaluate(function() {
    var form = document.querySelector('.form-control');
    form.selectedIndex = 2;
    $(form).change();
});
```

If you don't already have jQuery in the page, you can inject it like this if you have jQuery locally:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts: [ "jquery.min.js" ]
});
```

or if you don't have it locally:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    remoteScripts: [ "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" ]
});
```

Comment: above solution worked...thanks., but after that when i execute the code, application becoming unresponsive...and without executing it is quitting the script.

Comment: thanks above solution worked only when i type some code, and the i change the drop down but when i change the drop down value before entering code, it starts to execute the empty cell. it is not going to the next line of the code which is adding code into the cell

Comment: What does *"code"* in *"solution worked only when i type some code"* mean? Are you talking about something that needs to be typed in on the page? If yes, then I can't help you, because I don't know the page you're talking about.

Comment: Hey, can i use xpath for the above solution? if then how can i use that one?

Comment: Sure, simpy use `document.evaluate()` inside of `casper.evaluate()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596417/is-there-a-way-to-get-element-by-xpath-in-javascript

Comment: casper.then(function(){
        this.evaluate(function() {
        var form = document.getElementById({type:'xpath', path:"/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/select/option[3]"});
 });
});

Comment: `document.getElementById()` doesn't work like this, you need to use `document.evaluate()` to query elements based on XPaths. The link in my previous comment provides everything you need.

Comment: i used the below code as you mentioned,
casper.then(function(){
 document.evaluate(function() {
   return document.getElementById({type:'xpath', path:"/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/select/option[3]"});
 });
});
but it is throwing error 
TypeError: Not enough arguments to Document.evaluate.
#    type: uncaughtError
#    file: run_all/sample.js
#    error: {}
#    stack: not provided

Comment: This is completely wrong. You don't need to use `getElementById` at all. It seems you haven't read the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14284815) properly.

Comment: hey i gone through it but i am not getting it completely..i am using document.evaluate(".//*[@id='part1.R']/div[2]/div[2]/select", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null); but still not getting

Comment: Why do you use `XPathResult.ANY_TYPE` when you only expect one element? Use `XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE`.

Comment: nope...still it is showing, Not enough arguments to Document.evaluate error.please look in to the code https://gist.github.com/tejas1493/18cedde89e7b09820446

Comment: As I said before `document.evaluate()` works on the DOM, so it must be called inside of the page context (`casper.evaluate()`).

Comment: ya i placed it under casper.evaluate(function(){ now but still, it is not switching

Comment: Not all CasperJS functions are asynchronous. `wait` and `then` are, but `evaluate` is not. You need to put the evaluate block into a step if the `wait(3000)` is important: `this.wait(3000, function(){ this.echo(this.evaluate(function(){ return !!document.evaluate("//*[@id='part1.R']/div[2]/div[2]/select", document, null,XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}); })) })` This should print true if the element is there.