# Finding an element using xpath of javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, xpath, appium

I'm working on mobile automation on iOS platform using the following:

**Selenium WebDriver: 2.47**

**Appium dot net driver: 1.4.0.3**

**Appium: 1.4.8**

I want find a element using xpath and click on it. But I don't want to use the native methods of Selenium webdriver.

I want to perform this operation using javascript.

I have tried the following:

## 1

```
_driver.ExecuteScript("window.document.evaluate(\"//a[contains(text(),'Log In')]\", document.lastChild, null,XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).click()");
```

## 2

```
IList<IWebElement> buttons = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[contains(text(),'Log In')]"));
           _driver.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", buttons[0]);
```

## 3

```
_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(text(),'Log In')]")).Click();
```

I'm able to switch to webviews but unable to click on this particular elment.
In the second method, I can see that I can fetch the element but calling click() method is not clicking the element.

Thanks in advance. I'm stuck here for two days now.

## update:

Here is the html of the button I want to click on:

```
<a class="btn btn-outline white slide-demo" data-slide-target=".slide-wrap">Log In</a>
```

Comment: You should probably provide the HTML for the element that you are trying to find.

Comment: Why the requirement for not using native Selenium methods?

Comment: It not my requirement. Its just that the native selenium methods are not working in iOS devices. I have also updated my question with the HTML. Please take a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

The following example demonstrates a generic non-IE syntax for finding all H3 containing ‘XPath’ using an XPath query:

```
var result = document.evaluate("//h3[contains(text(),'XPath')]",
document.documentElement, null,
XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null)

        for (var i=0; i<result.snapshotLength; i++) {
            alert(result.snapshotItem(i).innerHTML)
        }
```

[This link might be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596417/is-there-a-way-to-get-element-by-xpath-using-javascript-in-selenium-webdriver) Also Check out [This Tutorial](http://javascript.info/tutorial/searching-elements-dom)

Comment: The tutorial has 5 ways of querying an element excluding xpath. But there is no syntax for querying an element with xpath. A simple example is appreciated. Thanks