# Python selenium - modifying the source code of a webpage

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Python selenium to automate my attendance entry. It was working fine, now I wanted to try by modifying the source code. I have seen few posts stating that it can be modified using `driver.execute_script()` and it works for JavaScript, but in my case I need to modify a source code under the `select` tag. I was able to modify the source code using the `inspect element`. The following is `select` tags source code:

```
<select name="date1">
    <option value="2016-09-17">2016-09-17</option>
    <option value="2016-09-16">2016-09-16</option>
    <option value="2016-09-14">2016-09-14</option>
</select>
```

I tried to do it with `driver.execute_script()`. The following was my code:

```
sel = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/select')
input_list = sel.find_element_by_tag_name('option')
cmd = "input_list.value = '2016-09-07'"
driver.execute_script(cmd)
```

But the above code is giving me the following error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: input_list is not defined

I am able to modify the source code using the `inspect element` window. Is there any way to modify the source code using selenium?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try following solution and let me know if any issues occurs:

```
driver.execute_script("""document.querySelector("select[name='date1'] option").value="2016-09-07";""")
```

P.S. I advise you not to use absolute `XPath` in your selectors, but relative instead

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. There was a small error in the code, I edited it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `execute_script` executes JavaScript inside the browser [1], which knows nothing about python variables in python script. In particuar `input_list` is not defined for JavaScript, since it's a python variable.

To fix this, you can select the element inside the JavaScript file. To do this, you can set your cmd to something like this [2]:

```js
    function getElementByXpath(path) {
      return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
    }

    getElementByXpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/select/option[1]").value = '2016-09-07';
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div>
          <form>
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>
                    <select name="date1">
                      <option value="2016-09-17">2016-09-17</option>
                      <option value="2016-09-16">2016-09-16</option>
                      <option value="2016-09-14">2016-09-14</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[1] https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script

[2] [Is there a way to get element by Xpath using JavaScript in Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596417/is-there-a-way-to-get-element-by-xpath-using-javascript-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the script suggested by Anderson worked without any additional JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

in **python** use this :

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("some-random-number")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = 'change text'", element)
```