# How to change HTML code of a webpage in python | Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

This page page has a list of phone codes, I need to change the selected country code, it can be done by adding this

```
        <option value="ua">380+ country</option>
        <option value="ug">256+ country</option>
--->    <option value="uk" **selected**="">44+ country</option>
        <option value="uy">598+ country</option>
        <option value="uz">7+ country</option>
        <option value="ve">58+ country</option>
        <option value="vn">84+ country</option>
        <option value="ws">685+ country</option>
        <option value="ye">967+ country</option>
        <option value="yu">381+ country</option>
        <option value="za">27+ country</option>
```

so how can I write 'selected' anywhere I want with selenium?

Comment: one way I can think of is to get the whole html document, and then string format it, then run it locally, so as an html document it will at least have the visual appearance

Comment: can this be an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543237/python-selenium-modifying-the-source-code-of-a-webpage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have shown only `options` tag from `HTML structure`.

They must be child of `Select tag in HTML`.

Basically `Select` and `option` tags are meant to build a drop down.

You can select them like this  :

```
menu = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "xpath of select web element"))
menu.select_by_value("ua")
```