# Get value within a form document.queryselector using the count of nodes

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am trying to get the values for tracking of an E-commerce website. The values are stored in a form with this selector the element is just in the td. :

```
form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td:nth-child(3) > b
```

As part of the selector, this is normal. But The **tr:nth-child(5)** is growing each time a new product is added the child grows so if have 2 products this will be **tr:nth-child(6)** and so on. I try to capture the count of element with `document.querySelectorAll(selector).length` but no luck. is there another way to get the value if the node children are increasing?

I am kind of new to scrapping with javascript.

Thanks.
George

Comment: will this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/14284815/1018054

Comment: reach till tbody from queryselectorall and then use siblings to determine what data you want , further you can also use queryselectorall.

Comment: Thank I used a different strategy I took the ".childNodes" to get the length and from then I start to work.