# Having Trouble Using XPath to Select LI Containing Specific Text

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, xpath

Here is the HTML for the list item:

```
<li class="disabled-result" data-option-array-index="1" style="">4" (0)</li>
```

And here is the JS I'm trying to use, which isn't working:

```
var xpath = "li[contains(.,'4"')]";
var matchingElement = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
matchingElement.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;" ) !important' );
```

Ideally I would just assign an ID to the list item I want to hide, but this is a Wordpress website and that makes it difficult to do.

Something I noticed is that in the page source, the `<li>` html doesn't show up (only in inspector). I have the JS running in the footer.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I've been scratching my head over this.

(I also tried this without the `var matchingElement` line. I'm not very familiar yet with using Xpath, and in the past have mostly used queryselector.)

Edit: Here is the entire code for the `<UL>`

```
<ul class="chosen-results">
<li class="active-result result-selected" data-option-array-index="0" style="">Size</li>
<li class="disabled-result" data-option-array-index="1" style="">4" (0)</li>
<li class="disabled-result" data-option-array-index="2" style="">5" (0)</li>
<li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3" style="">Extra Large (5)</li>
<li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="4" style="">Large (7)</li>
<li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="5" style="">Medium (8)</li>
<li class="disabled-result" data-option-array-index="6" style="">Small (0)</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this will fix the rest of the code, but your xpath needs to have "//" in front of it.  You would know this if you tried to test your xpath in firebug or the elements dom of chrome.

```
var xpath = "//li[contains(.,'4"')]";
```

//do this just like this.

```
var xpath = "//li[contains(.,'4\"')]";
var matchingElement = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
matchingElement.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;" ) !important' );
```

//the code I'm using, that removes the element just as intended.

```
<ul class="chosen-results">
<li class="active-result result-selected" data-option-array-index="0" style="">Size</li>
<li class="disabled-result" data-option-array-index="1" style="">4" (0)</li>
<li class="disabled-result" data-option-array-index="2" style="">5" (0)</li>
<li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3" style="">Extra Large (5)</li>
<li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="4" style="">Large (7)</li>
<li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="5" style="">Medium (8)</li>
<li class="disabled-result" data-option-array-index="6" style="">Small (0)</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
var xpath = "//li[contains(.,'4\"')]";
var matchingElement = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
matchingElement.setAttribute('style', 'display: none !important;')
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I added the `//` but it still isn't working. I did check the elements panel of the chrome inspector, but I wasn't seeing anything about the Javascript so maybe I'm not quite using it correctly.

Comment: Ok, so I ran your code in the console.  Your getting a invalid or unexpected token when running the first line of var xpath.  Reason is because of the double quote.  As Monkey Coder stated, do the escape, but instead of using double quotes again around 4, do single quotes.  Like this: `var xpath = "//li[contains(.,'4\"')]";`

Comment: Hm, it still isn't working but now I'm getting the error cannot read property `setAttribute` of null.

Comment: I'm having the feeling you have more than one item on the page that is matching the xpath.  I just tried two of the same element and it returned back 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null
    at <anonymous>:1:17'

Comment: I just tried `var xpath = "//li[contains(.,'4\" ')][1]";` which is returning the same error.

Comment: With the above posted UL, your code works fine.  Is there another UL on the page?  Can you post the link to the source so I can check what's going on?  I'm having a feeling you have two of the same elements on the same page.

Comment: The copy I'm working on with 4" added to sizes is being worked on and password protected, but I will add the entire page's code above in my question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Before you do that, see my edit and see if you're running it exactly as I have it.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add the code because it's too large. Here is a link to the original page, which doesn't include my 4" size but is otherwise about the same: [link](https://www.architecturalmailboxes.com/product_category/post-mount-mailboxes/)

Comment: Yeah, I dunno what your doing, I've done exactly what you have done with javascript at the bottom in the footer of the page and it works just fine for me.  It removes the "4" size as you wrote it.

Comment: Hey IamBatman, I double checked and am still getting the same error. Edit: interesting. Ok, thank you for your help.

Comment: Can I ask why you're adding another paranthesis and a css property outside of the style?  This is what you are creating `<li class="disabled-result" data-option-array-index="1" style="display: none" ) !important">4" (0)</li>`

Comment: You know, I'm actually not sure but it didn't seem to work properly when I did `matchingElement.setAttribute('style', 'display: none !important;" );`

Comment: Seriously look at the code you just commented with above.  We just went over this.  You need to escape quotes and then put a single quote to close it.  `matchingElement.setAttribute('style', 'display: none !important;\"');`

Comment: and fyi, you don't need to close it off when your are setting an attribute you can just do this:  `matchingElement.setAttribute('style', 'display: none !important;');`

Comment: Ok my mistake, I've corrected that but still this same error. My exact code is ```var xpath = "//li[contains(.,'4\"')]";
var matchingElement = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
matchingElement.setAttribute('style', 'display: none !important;\"')```

Comment: Yeah, it works for me.  Sorry I couldn't help you any further.  Hope you figure it out.

Comment: My best advice I could give you to debug this yourself is to do the following:  Step 1.)  Open the console when on your page.  2.)  Enter you first line:  var xpath = "//li[contains(.,'4\"')]"; 3.)  Press enter.  4.)  If it says undefined, it may of worked, so lets check what it found.  5.)  type in the var name "xpath" and press enter.  6.)  If it returns the element we are looking for it's not your xpath.  Move on to the next one and repeat.  Once you find the error, look at that line and figure out why it's doing it.

Comment: If it's the xpath, go back to elements, do a find and put your xpath in "//li[contains(.,'4\"')]", is it finding it?  If so, is it more than one found?  If so, maybe need to narrow it down to just the one you want.  Try a different xpath locator or use indexes like you tried before maybe?  Just throwing out some helpful tips in debugging.

Comment: It's complaining about a null value with setAttribute, which usually means document.evaluate didn't find anything leaving matchingElement "null" as in "empty".

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code below:

`var xpath = "//li[contains(text(), '4\"')]";
var matchingElement = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
matchingElement.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;" ) !important' );`

you could also try:

`var xpath = "//li[@class = 'disabled-result' and contains(text(), '4\"')]"`

Comment: I see that my use of the `"` was incorrect, but alas this isn't working either.

Comment: I forgot the double slash for var xpath, could you try the edited one and see?

Comment: Well, it still isn't working and I've tried that and other variations that I could think of. The error I'm seeing now is `cannot read property setAttribute of null`.

Comment: try `var xpath = "//li[@class = 'disabled-result' and @data-option-array-index='1']"`

Comment: I don't think it's an xpath problem anymore, we've opened up an error with I think their document.evaluate line.  How many items are in this list?  Can we get the code for all items in the unordered list?

Comment: I am receiving the same error unfortunately. Sure, I have added it to my question above.

Comment: [Go to this link and check at the most liked comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596417/is-there-a-way-to-get-element-by-xpath-using-javascript-in-selenium-webdriver) and just use `var xpath = "//li[@class = 'disabled-result' and @data-option-array-index='1']"` should work.

Comment: I went there and tried it, but it still isn't working.