# I am looking for something like this for auto click by xpath

Tags: javascript

```js
getElementByXpath("//html[1]/body[1]/div[1]").click();
```

I am looking for something like this for auto click by xpath but is not working

Comment: What is you html?

Comment: is just example bro

Comment: //*[@id="IDBodyPanelapp"]/div[1]

Comment: Please give us some context and explanation around: __Which `div` or button element__ inside your HTML do you want to click via JavaScript? Have you access to the .JS file (are you experienced in Javascript) or do you just want the browser to do some automatic magic?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.evaluate` to find element by Xpath. After that, you can call `click()` to click on it. Here's an example:

```js
function getElementByXpath(path) {
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}

getElementByXpath('//button[@id="IDBodyPanelapp"]').click();
```

```html
<button id="IDBodyPanelapp" onclick="alert('Button clicked!')">test</button>
```

More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14284815/7919626

Comment: i need for auto click

Comment: @aminolok it does click automatically. What do you mean by auto click?

Comment: look like this  : document.getElementById('category').click();    this click automaticlly on category

Comment: i need the same but with xpath please

Comment: @aminolok this is exactly what my example does. I edited it to make it easier to understand.

Comment: ah okey thank you bro .  i use it but is not working :(