# Is there any equivalent to selenium FindElements By.XPath in chrome extension java script?

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, google-chrome-extension, getelementbyid

I have some experience in Selenium, using some code as below to locate elements using XPath;

```
var btns = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(@"//button[(@type='submit')]"));
```

I recently started to develop an Chrome extension, and I could not find any similar way to locate elements using easier way similar to XPath.

I'm having many complex queries developed in selenium, using the XPath methods. I just want to do the same in Chrome Extension to locate elements.

I could only locate element in Chrome Extension content script as the method below;

```
const contents = document.getElementById('contents');
```

Can anyone please suggest me the **best way to convert XPath to Chrome Extension content script** without many modifications, and some way similar to XPath in Selenium? (My XPath statements are complex a bit)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to get element by XPath using JavaScript in Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596417/is-there-a-way-to-get-element-by-xpath-using-javascript-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Use the standard built-in DOM method `document.evaluate`. You can also find a library that simplifies using it or write one yourself, it's just a few lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) like this:

```
document.evaluate("//xpath/here", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
```