# Locate web elements with JavaScript by CSS Selector or XPath?

Tags: javascript, css, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

While creating Selenium automation tests sometimes we need to retrieve a web element with JavaScript, not with Selenium `driver.findElement`.
So, I know we can do something like

```
javaScript = "document.getElementsByClassName('myClassName')[0].click();"
driver.execute_script(javaScript)
```

I see we can locate elements in this way `ByClassName`, `ByName`, `ByTagName` and `BytagNameNS` but in most cases element can be uniquely located with CSS Selector or XPath only while I couldn't see such way in [documentations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) and [tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp).
So, I'm wondering is it possible to locate web elements with JavaScript by XPath or CSS Selectors?

Comment: CSS selectors can be used via [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). For XPath you can use [evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) -> [Locating DOM elements using selectors - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors), [Is there a way to get element by XPath using JavaScript in Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596417)

Comment: For Xpath with JavaScript see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelector() //for single node with css like path or selector

document.querySelectorAll() //for multiple nodes
```

To select by ID:

```
document.querySelector('#ID') //returns single element
document.querySelectorAll('#ID') //returns node list, you may need to use forEach
```

To select by class:

```
document.querySelector('.class') //returns single element
document.querySelectorAll('.class') //returns node list, you may need to use forEach
```

To select inside div by class:

```
document.querySelector('div > .class') //returns single element
document.querySelectorAll('div > .class') //returns node list, you may need to use forEach
```

Here is the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: _"To select by ...:"_ is not code, hence it shouldn't be formatted as such. And there are definitely similar questions here on SO.