# How to get Element by XPATH in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xpath

I have a very basic code. It simply changes the style of the button on click. It works fine when used `getElementById` but I wanna do it the `XPATH` way. I'm new to JavaScript. What I'm doing wrong and how can I achieve this?

**The code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Click the button to change the layout of this paragraph</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  let x = document.getElementByXpath("//html[1]/body[1]/button[1]");
  x.style.fontSize = "25px"; 
  x.style.color = "red"; 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is no `document.getElementByXpath` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate

Comment: And there is a lot better ways to do this without XPATH.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to get element by XPath using JavaScript in Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596417/is-there-a-way-to-get-element-by-xpath-using-javascript-in-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Look at [document.evaluate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate)

```js
function getElementByXpath(path) {
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}

function myFunction() {
  let x = getElementByXpath("//html[1]/body[1]/button[1]");
  x.style.fontSize = "25px"; 
  x.style.color = "red"; 
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">Click the button to change the layout of this paragraph</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for this. It worked! However, I've a question tho. What does `.singleNodeValue` do? Can you explain the code?

Comment: @Abhaysalvi [singleNodeValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XPathResult/singleNodeValue)