# Click only first button with some "text" on it, instead all of them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a script that clicks a button every 31 seconds.
That website contains many buttons with the classes `reply-markup-button rp tgico`. To select the exact button I am looking for, I am looking for the exact text on the button using `document.getElementByTagName` and a for-loop:

```js
var viewAdsButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var viewAdsButtonText = "View ads";

setInterval(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < viewAdsButton.length; i++) {
    if (viewAdsButton[i].textContent == viewAdsButtonText) {
      viewAdsButton[i].click()
    }
  }
}, 31000);
```

```html
<button class='reply-markup-button rp tgico' onclick="console.log('button 1')">View ads</button>
<button class='reply-markup-button rp tgico' onclick="console.log('button 2')">View ads</button>
<button class='reply-markup-button rp tgico' onclick="console.log('button 3')">Don't View ads</button>
<button class='reply-markup-button rp tgico' onclick="console.log('button 4')">View ads</button>
```

The issue is that there are also many buttons with "View ads" on them, and I only want the script to click **the first one** instead of all of them.

Comment: Add a `break;` or `return;` after your call to `viewAdsButton[i].click();` so the loop exits after clicking the first button.

Comment: Use `break` within the if condition to break out of the for loop once the condition has been satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Add a call to `break` (or `return`) after you click the first matching button:

```
var viewAdsButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var viewAdsButtonText = "View ads";


setInterval(function(){ 
  for (var i = 0; i < viewAdsButton.length; i++) {
    if (viewAdsButton[i].textContent == viewAdsButtonText) {
      viewAdsButton[i].click()
      break // Stop looping
    }
  }
}, 31000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are many buttons, don't try to use `document.getElementsByTagName` or `document.getElementsByClassName`. They return a collection of elements and it's much harder to find the exact element you want. Also consider this: what if two buttons have the same text, or the website updates and the button text changes?

Here are some better approaches:

First, look at the button in your browser's dev tools. If it has an ID, then use `document.getElementsById`. Like this:

```
var viewAdsButton = document.getElementsById("some-button-id");

setInterval(function() { 
    viewAdsButton.click();
}, 31000);
```

If the button doesn't have an ID, then you should get the element by its XPath. An XPath is just a string that uniquely represents an element in the DOM hierarchy, but this isn't too important. You can copy the elements XPath in the dev tools (Copy -> Copy XPath). Use this code for the XPath:

```
var viewAdsButton = document.evaluate("some-button-xpath", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;

setInterval(function() { 
    viewAdsButton.click();
}, 31000);
```

(See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69754592/13376511) for more on getting an element by its XPath)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `getElementsByTagName()`, I grabbed the first button with the classes you listed using `querySelector()`. Then you can just add a click event inside the `setInterval()` function without looping through anything.

I also used `querySelectorAll()` and did a `forEach()` loop to add an onclick event listener to every button with those classes, to show that the `setInterval()` function was only clicking the first one.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button.reply-markup-button.rp.tgico')
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('button.reply-markup-button.rp.tgico')
const btnText = 'View ads'

setInterval(() => {
  btn.click()
}, 500)

btns.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => e.target.classList.toggle('red')))
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class='reply-markup-button rp tgico'>View ads</button>
<button class='reply-markup-button rp tgico'>View ads</button>
<button class='reply-markup-button rp tgico'>Don't View ads</button>
<button class='reply-markup-button rp tgico'>View ads</button>
```