# Change content in HTML with javascript

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel VBA to change content in HTML, I found the following command and it works fine, but when I try to assign the value of a cell in excel it gives an error, please help.

`Driver.ExecuteScript ("document.getElementById('tieudeChart').innerHTML = 'textaaa';")`

Error: javascripterror: cell1 is not defined

```
cell1 = Main_AT.Range("ae5").Value
Driver.ExecuteScript ("document.getElementById('tieudeChart').innerHTML= cell1;")
```

Comment: Maybe: `Driver.ExecuteScript ("document.getElementById('tieudeChart').innerHTML= " & cell1 & ";")` ?? OR maybe: `Driver.ExecuteScript ("document.getElementById('tieudeChart').innerHTML= '" & cell1 & "';")`

Answer (score 1):

You want the variable outside of the quotes, and since it's a string, put single quotes around it like this:

```
Driver.ExecuteScript "document.getElementById('tieudeChart').innerHTML= '" & cell1 & "';"
```

<sub>Note: This assumes `cell1` does not have a single quote in it.</sub>

This should handle the cell having quotes.

```
Driver.ExecuteScript "document.getElementById('tieudeChart').innerHTML= '" & Replace(cell1, "'", "''") & "';"
```

Comment: It's very useful. Can you help me this command with document.getelementbyxpath gives error "document.getelementbyxpath is not function"??

Comment: no idea if this will help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596417/is-there-a-way-to-get-element-by-xpath-using-javascript-in-selenium-webdriver  - but that's a separate question